# Why is there an error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'P_Name_t' from type 'UINT8 *'

Tags: c, arrays, struct, assignment-operator

I don't understand why I am getting the error above and how to fix it. Please help.

```
//STRUCTURES
typedef UINT8 P_Name_t[5];
typedef UINT8 ChipSN_t[3]; 

typedef struct                   
{  
   ChipSN_t  ChipSN; 
   <other members>   
} ChipIdent_t;


typedef struct Data_t              
{ 
   ChipIdent_t      ReadOnlyMemID;
    <other members>   
} Data_t;


typedef struct                
{
   P_Name_t NameOfPart;   
   <other members>
} Log_t;

Data_t     Data_Src;

typedef struct
{
   P_Name_t       NameOfPart;           
   ChipSN_t       ChipSN;   
}PartNum_ID_t;


//VARIABLE DECALARTION
PRIVATE PartNum_ID_t PN_ChipID[12]; 
PRIVATE Log_t   *LogEntry = NULL;               


//Usage in code
PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart = LogEntry->NameOfPart; 
PN_ChipID[0].ChipSN = Data_Src.ReadOnlyMemID.ChipSN;
```

I don't understand why I get the error. The `LogEntry->NameOfPart` is of type `P_Name_t` and `PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart` is of the same type. I don't know if I am missing something here. Please explain.

Comment: 1. First rule of C programming **do not** `typedef` pointers. 2. Second rule of C programming **do not** use `_t` for the name of custom types (see POSIX). 3. Third rule -- see 1 and 2.

Comment: Make an [mcve] please. With what you provided there is too much guessing going on.

Comment: @0andriy: I agree with the first rule, not with the second, that would be a rule for the POSIX programmer, and there is C beyond POSIX. I'd say that the second rule is : **do not** `typedef` arrays!.

Comment: You are attempting to assign a value of type `UINT8*` to an lvalue of type `UINT8[5]`.  Arrays and pointers are not the same thing; the assignment is invalid.

Comment: That's what happen when you try to obfuscate your code by unnecessary typedefing pointers and arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> incompatible types when assigning to type 'P_Name_t' [...]
> ```
>
> [...] why i get the error[?] The `LogEntry->NameOfPart` is of type `P_Name_t` and `PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart` is of the same type.

`P_Name_t` is an array, namely of 5 `unit8_t`.

`PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart` is of type `P_Name_t`.

So this line

```
PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart = LogEntry->NameOfPart;
```

tries to assign to an array, namely to `PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart`.

In C it is *not possible* to assign to an array, hence the error during compilation of the above line.

Comment: For the benefit of this thread and future answer seekers. `LogEntry->NameOfPart` is an array of 5 elements, namely  `LogEntry->NameOfPart[0]', `LogEntry->NameOfPart[1]', `LogEntry->NameOfPart[2]', `LogEntry->NameOfPart[3]', `LogEntry->NameOfPart[4]', `LogEntry->NameOfPart[5]'. 'PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart` is similar 'PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart[0]', 'PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart[1]', 'PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart[2]' and so on.. So the way to copy this is to  run it through a loop copying element by element  `PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart[i] = LogEntry->NameOfPart[i];`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from hiding it behind complicated structs and pointers,
you are basically trying to do this:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[5];
    char b[5]={'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

    // version 1 works
    memcpy(a, b, sizeof(b)); // assuming that a and b are same size.

    // version 2 gives the same error as you quote
    //a=b;

    return 0;    
}
```

It gives the same error.
While array identifiers used as R-values decay to pointers,
you cannot "write to the pointer" representing an array as L-value.

Besides, what do you want to achieve?
What you anyway need to do is to copy the content of one array to the other.
Use memcpy() or any other method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of this thread and future answer seekers. `LogEntry->NameOfPart` is an array of 5 elements, namely:

```
LogEntry->NameOfPart[0]
LogEntry->NameOfPart[1] 
LogEntry->NameOfPart[2] 
LogEntry->NameOfPart[3]
LogEntry->NameOfPart[4]
```

and

`PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart` is similar

```
PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart[0] 
PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart[1]
PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart[2]
PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart[3]
PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart[4]
```

So the way to copy this is to  run it through a loop copying element by element

```
for i=....
{
  PN_ChipID[0].NameOfPart[i] = LogEntry->NameOfPart[i];
}
```